# PHP Json Decoded Array is not listing

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am trying to customize a plugin in Wordpress,written a code to list the data taken from DB,after the Json decode the array is being listed,but i tried using for and for each loop,for both it is not listing.There is no error displayed,it just show blank.

Wordpress Page Template-

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: List Guide
 */
get_header();
?>
<?php

$query = $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT
       post_content
    FROM 
        wp_posts
    WHERE 
        ID = 7
    ", 
    $ID
);

$string = $wpdb->get_var( $query );

$someArray = json_decode( $string );
print_r($someArray);
die;




 echo  $count = count( $someArray ); 

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) { ?> 

     <?php echo $someArray->locations[$i]->title; ?> 

<?php } ?>



<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

### OUTPUT

> Array ( [mapwidth] => 637 [mapheight] => 586 [minimap] =>
> [clearbutton] => 1 [zoombuttons] => 1 [sidebar] => 1 [search] => 1
> [hovertip] => 1 [mousewheel] => 1 [fullscreen] => [deeplinking] => 1
> [mapfill] => [zoom] => 1 [alphabetic] => 1 [zoomlimit] => 3 [action]
> => tooltip [categories] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => clothing [title] => CLOTHING [color] => [show] => false ) [1] => Array ( [id]
> => jewelryandaccessories [title] => JEWELRY & ACCESSORIES [color] => [show] => false ) [2] => Array ( [id] => shoes [title] => SHOES
> [color] => [show] => false ) [3] => Array ( [id] => beautyandhealth
> [title] => BEAUTY & HEALTH [color] => [show] => false ) [4] => Array (
> [id] => fitness [title] => FITNESS [color] => [show] => false ) [5] =>
> Array ( [id] => restaurantsandcafe [title] => RESTAURANTS & CAFE’S
> [color] => [show] => false ) [6] => Array ( [id] => homeanddesign
> [title] => HOME & DESIGN [color] => [show] => false ) [7] => Array (
> [id] => hotelsandhospitality [title] => HOTELS & HOSPITALITY [color]
> => [show] => false ) [8] => Array ( [id] => artgalleries [title] => ART GALLERIES [color] => [show] => false ) [9] => Array ( [id] =>
> specialtyandother [title] => SPECIALTY & OTHER [color] => [show] =>
> false ) ) [levels] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => soho001 [title]
> => Soho [map] => //dotzserver.com/soho/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Map-for-Web_V21.svg
> [minimap] => [locations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => location965
> [title] => Rag & Bone [description] =>
>
> [pin] => purple no-fill [link] => https://www.rag-bone.com/ [category]
> => clothing [action] => default [x] => 0.5018 [y] => 0.4627 [fill] => #ffffff ) [1] => Array ( [id] => location133 [title] => Near Subway [pin] => no-fill [fill] => #ffffff [category] => restaurantsandcafe
> [action] => default [x] => 0.5021 [y] => 0.3250 ) [2] => Array ( [id]
> => location359 [title] => Yay [pin] => yellow no-fill [fill] => #ffffff [category] => homeanddesign [action] => default [x] => 0.4194 [y] => 0.3798 ) ) ) ) [maxscale] => 3 [zoomoutclose] => [fillcolor] =>
>
> ## 8224e3 [topLat] => [leftLng] => [bottomLat] => [rightLng] => [smartip] => [thumbholder] => [height] => auto ) 28

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The array to be called was in such a format-

```
foreach ($someArray['levels'] as $arr){ 

       foreach ($arr['locations'] as $locationarr){ 
            echo $locationarr['title']
       }
}
```